# Adding multiple conditions to MySQL Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

the goal of the query is also to find possible duplicates of names that were mistyped. Example:

`International Group Inc.` must be find as a duplicate of `International, Group Inc`

In order to accomplish this a used the next query:

```
SELECT C.id,
       C.name,
       C.address,
       C.city_id
FROM   company C
       INNER JOIN (SELECT name
                   FROM   company
                   GROUP  BY name
                   HAVING Count(id) > 1) D
               ON Replace(Replace(C.name, '.', ''), ',', '') =
                  Replace(Replace(D.name, '.', ''), ',', '')
```

It works very well and the result came at `40 secs` but adding an extra condition like `AND C.city_id='4'` requires an extra minute or more; This is still acceptable but not preferable.

My real problem occurs when I try to add another condition to find out only duplicates of companies that have a specific string in the name, using this condition `AND C.name LIKE '%International%'`, this just don't return any results.

Could somebody help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can make efficient use of indexes in this scenario - although 1 minute + does seem extremely slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are joining on the result of a function, the query cannot use any index. Besides, the cost of executing the `REPLACE()` on all rows is probably not negligible.

I suggest you first add an indexed column that receives the "stripped-down" version of the strings, and then run the query with a join on this column:

```
ALTER TABLE company ADD COLUMN stripped_name VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE company ADD INDEX(stripped_name);
UPDATE TABLE company SET stripped_name = REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '.', ''), ',', '') ;
```

Running the `UPDATE` could take a while the first time, but you could also set an `ON UPDATE` and an `ON INSERT` triggers on `company` so that `stripped_name` gets populated and update on-the-fly.

Comment: That's a great idea - and obvious (even though I didn't think of it!)

Comment: This solution really increments the performance, but I still can't get the result when looking for a specific string in the name of the company using `AND E.stripped_name LIKE '%International%'`. Why could it be?

Comment: @gustyaquino Are you sure there is a matching row? You might also be using a case-sensitive collation. Please show us the full structure of your table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE company;`)

Comment: @YaK of course, I used an example not actually in the database. Thank you, great help!

Answer (score 0):

Try starting from the tmp table because foreach row in company a tmp table will be created :

```
SELECT C.id,
       C.name,
       C.address,
       C.city_id
FROM (SELECT name
                   FROM   company
                   GROUP  BY name
                   HAVING Count(id) > 1) D  
INNER JOIN company C       
               ON Replace(Replace(C.name, '.', ''), ',', '') =
                  Replace(Replace(D.name, '.', ''), ',', '')
```